# Create a REST API for lower version of spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rest

I am unable to create a REST API for lower version of Spring like Spring 3.0 as @RestController can't be used. Can you please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

Use [@Controller](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller) if you can't use yet `@RestController`

> Classic controllers can be annotated with the @Controller annotation. This is simply a specialization of the @Component class and allows implementation classes to be autodetected through the classpath scanning.

> @Controller is typically used in combination with a @RequestMapping annotation used on request handling methods.

> @RestController is a specialized version of the controller. It includes the @Controller and @ResponseBody annotations and as a result, simplifies the controller implementation

Comment: whenever i am using Controller and then in RequestMapping, i am receiving "HTTP Status 404:Not found"

Answer (score 0):

`@RestController` is not an absolute must for REST API, you can do this with `@Controller`.

Your method should look something like this, request method can be `GET/POST`. It is producing json, you can give other options.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/desiredValueHere.do", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> uploadResponseDoc(@ModelAttribute("referenceName") DesiredModelAttribute bForm) throws IOException, Exception {
        // call your service class, utils, etc to prepare the response.
}
```

Comment: whenever i am using Controller and then in RequestMapping, i am receiving "HTTP Status 404:Not found" . Please suggest if there is any other change i need to make

Comment: mind posting your controller, at least the method declaration and @Controller annotation you have used.